# Verifying the issuer of digital certificate?

Tags: cryptography, digital-certificate

I am developing an application in C++. Here i am performing some encryption and decryption using the digital certificates. My objective is that a user with an valid digital certificate should only be allow to proceed. Here a valid digital certificate means the one issued by CA(certificate authority). Now for example we can create our own digital certificate like [this](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-help/create-your-own-digital-certificate-HP005249558.aspx).
My objective is to verify the issuer of the digital certificate and check the validity based on the issuer.

What i need here is the exact CryptoAPI to perform above operation? If you have any other suggestion to achieve the above mentioned objective then i would be very grateful.

Thanks in advance for you help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CA will supply its root certificate which will provide the trust for your user certificate. You will build a chain to your root certificate to achieve this. Refer to [Certificate Chain Verification Functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa380252%28v=VS.85%29.aspx#certificate_chain_verification_functions)

You will also find other relevant functions that will allow you to validate the certificate itself using either CRL/OCSP.

If you are not familiar with cryptoAPI, a good starting will be to go through this book, [Performing X.509 Certificate Verification with CryptoAPI](http://etutorials.org/Programming/secure+programming/Chapter+10.+Public+Key+Infrastructure/10.6+Performing+X.509+Certificate+Verification+with+CryptoAPI/)